# Submanifold of a Lie group whose tangent bundle is invariant under group (left) action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

**Edit:** According to the interesting comment of Tobias Fritz we revise the question.

Assume that $G$ is a Lie group and $M\subseteq G$ is a closed  connected smooth submanifold of $G$ containing the neutral element $e\in G$. Assume that for every $m\in M$ we have $D L_m (T_e M)=T_m M$. This means that the differential of left multiplication by $m$ preserves the corresponding tangent space to $M$.

> Does this impliy that $M$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Doesn't your condition hold for $M$ being any open neighbourhood of $e$?

Comment: @TobiasFritz  thank you for this interesting comment. I revise the question.

Comment: You also may want to assume connectedness, since otherwise taking any set of connected components (containing the component of $e$) that is not a group provides another trivial counterexample.

Comment: @TobiasFritz  yes exactly  for example two horizontal line in the plane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Any subspace $V\subset\mathfrak g$ in the Lie algebra of $G$ defines a $G$-invariant distribution of planes in $TG$ via the action you have specified: $V_m=DL_m(V)$. This distribution is Frobenius-integrable iff $[V,V]\subset V$, i.e., $V$ is a Lie subalgebra. Note that by $G$-invariance $V$ is integrable at one point iff it is integrable everywhere.

By your assumption, $V$ is integrable, since $M$ is tangent to $V$ at all its points. Now, by the uniqueness of the solutions to ODEs $M$ must coincide with the Lie subgroup $\exp V$ (here we are using closedness and connectedness of $M$).

Comment: @Yuri Thank you and (+1) for this very interesting answer.