# Submanifold of Lie group whose tangent bundle is "almost" left-invariant

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group equipped with a left-invariant Riemannian metric, and let $M$ be a submanifold of $G$ containing the identity $e\in G$.

It is not difficult to show that, if the tangent bundle $TM$ is left-invariant, then $M$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$; see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280451/74033).

I am interested in understanding what happens if one relaxes such assumption a bit. In particular, suppose that the tangent bundle $TM$ admits an orthogonal splitting $TM = \varSigma_{1} \oplus \dotsb \oplus \varSigma_{n}$, where $\mathrm{rank} (\varSigma_{i}) \geq 2$, satisfying the following property:

**Property 1**. For each $i=1,\dotsc,n$ and $j\neq i$, the left-invariant extension of $\varSigma_{i} \lvert_{e}$ agrees with $\varSigma_{i}$ along $\varSigma_{j}$; in other words, for every curve $\gamma\, \colon [0,1] \to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=e$ and $\gamma'(t) \in \varSigma_{j}\lvert_{\gamma(t)}$ for all $t \in I$, we have $dL_{\gamma(t)}(\varSigma_{i}\lvert_{e}) = \varSigma_{i}\lvert_{\gamma(t)}$ for all $t \in I$.

One could also consider a more general condition:

**Property 2**. For each $i=1,\dotsc,n$ and $j\neq i$, the left-invariant extension of $\varSigma_{i} \lvert_{e}$ is tangent to $M$ along $\varSigma_{j}$, i.e., along every curve that starts at $e$ and is tangent to $\varSigma_{j}$.

**Questions**. Does either Property 1 or Property 2 imply that $M$ is a Lie subgroup? If not, what else can be said about $M$?

EDIT: In his comment, Joel Villatoro showed how to construct examples of submanifolds of $G$ that satisfy Property 1 (and so also 2) and are not Lie subgroups. The question now is whether it is possible to say anything more general about these properties. Are product submanifolds the only examples?

Comment: What is meant by the rank of $\Sigma_i$? (for Lie groups there is a notion of rank, which doesn't coincide with the dimension)

Comment: @YCor I mean the rank of the distribution $\varSigma_{i}$, i.e., the (constant) dimension of the vector space $\varSigma_{i}\lvert_{p}$

Comment: I would write this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation. What do you mean when you say distributions coincide *along a curve*? Coincidence seems like it should be a pointwise condition. To make this more of an answer: Let $H$ be any Lie group of dimension $ \ge 3$ and $N$ be a submanifold of $H$ of dimension $ \ge 2$ such that $e \in N$ but $N$ is not a subgroup. Then take $G = H \times H$ and $ M = N \times N$. Take $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ to be the distributions induced by the respective projections. Can you explain why this example does not satisfy your conditions?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have now edited the question. I need to think a bit more about your example.

Comment: @JoelVillatoro Your example indeed satisfies my conditions, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: For Property 1, aren't you also assuming that $I=[0,1]$ *and* that $\gamma(0)=e$?  Otherwise, you could simply take $\gamma(t)\equiv p\in M$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, and this would always satisfy your tangency condition, in which case you'd have that $\Sigma_i$ is fully left-invariant for all $i$, implying that $M$ is a subgroup of $G$.  Your formulation of Property 2 suffers the same problem unless you replace `every curve tangent to $\Sigma_j$' with 'every curve that starts at $e$ and is tangent to $\Sigma_j$'.

Comment: @RobertBryant I have now rephrased Property 1. Hope it is more clear. To me both conditions make sense without assuming that the curves pass from the identity. What am I missing?

Comment: @RobertBryant For instance, all I want to say in Property 2 is that, for all $j \neq i$, the left-invariant extension of $\varSigma_{i}\lvert_{e}$ is tangent to $M$ along $\varSigma_{j}$.

Comment: Your re-phrasings have not removed the problem.  Both Property 1 and Property 2 as stated immediately imply that the left-invariant extensions of the $(\Sigma_i)_e$ are tangent to $M$ at every point of $M$, so $M$ must be a Lie subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes, I see it now, thanks for clarifying! I'll edit the question.